# Using a custom plugin while using Cordova with Crosswalk in Android

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

Say I wan't to use Crosswalk in my Phonegap/Cordova-Project, because I need state of the art HTML5 & CSS3 features on Android 4.0 and higher. The crosswalks site is saying they support Cordova plugins, but can I write my own plugins and use them - even tough Crosswalk is used instead of the Android-WebView?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this document:
https://crosswalk-project.org/#documentation/cordova/add_plugins

Comment: Thanks, but I did want to know if someone already did add a custom plugin. At the bottom of the page it gives info on how to add IAP & AdMob Plugins that are not part of the Cordova plugins - I would be interested in using arbitrary third party plugins.